# Windows Git Linux Tools - Prevent SSH timeout in terminal

Tags: windows, ssh, git, timeout, terminal

I installed Git and included the Linux tools.

They rock, except for the SSH times out after five or ten minutes when I am running in the console. It just freezes the terminal until I hit a few buttons and then shows:

```
root@server:/home/username# Read from remote host example.com: Connection reset by peer
Connection to example.com closed.
```

I am running in Console2, for reference, but I think it just uses the system.

On another computer I have, it works fine. There is no timeout. I don't know why.

I have searched through the Linux tools for any SSH configuration settings to set timeout or keepalive and I cannot find any application config.

Does anybody know how to prevent this?

Comment: You may want to investigate keep alive settings for the ssh client you're using.

Comment: Is this 10 minutes of no activity, or when you're actively using that terminal session?

Comment: 10 minutes of no activity. I just need to find the keepalive setting really. I can't locate it for Linux tools for Windows.

Comment: On other Windows computers I have this timeout doesnt occur. It leaves the connection open until I close it.

Comment: Are those other systems connecting to the same server?  It might be a server-side session timeout.

Comment: No, there shouldn't be. It doesn't appear to be server side as far as I can tell. It appears to be client side. When I run SSH to the same server through Linux I do not get the same timeout. The only common factor I can see for this is Windows.